# Dockerize react app with mongo db docker-compose conection problem json error

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a mongodb -nodejs- react app and I can't make the production build work. The developer mode though is running fine And the individual production builds of Api and Ui work fine as well. The problem is probably at the nginx cause the ui can't post to the server when I try the log in mechanism I've built for example I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. and at my terminal : 172.20.0.1 - - [18/Dec/2021:13:25:49 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 405 559 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Ui Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:14.18.1 as build
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.21.4-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx","-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Api Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .

#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

nginx.config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  ui:
    build: ./my-app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: You seem to be missing something in your nginx.conf file that allows nginx to pass api calls through to the api container. Or do you make the POST call to port 8080?

Comment: The post is to localhost:8080 where my server is running but I'm not sure what should I do to allow the nginx to communicate with the 8080 port

Comment: If you post to port 8080, then nginx doesn't need to talk to the api container. The communication is from the browser directly to the api container. Can you make the POST request with a tool like `curl` or Postman to see what the response is?

Comment: I have no clue how to use them I just make a fetch request. But in that case since the developer mode is running why do I get error at the production. I mean shouldn't the communication stay the same since nginx isn't involved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want nginx to serve the API as well, lookup how to use `proxy_pass` in nginx or search "reverse proxy nginx". Currently, Nginx is only serving HTML pages, so any request to it will not return JSON, as the error says. Otherwise, your error indicates you've made a request to `localhost/login` or just `/login`, which is not the correct address for your api container